# problems using gson on xmlgregoriancalendar in android unable to include xerces2

Tags: android, rest, jaxb, gson, xerces

Iam facing with XmlGregorianCalendar convertion issue on android 2.3.X application project

iam building an android 2.3.X application that interact with Rest Services. Some objects provided by thes services have XMLGregorianCalendar datatype . these object classes have been generate throuth JAXB Binding.

on the android side i got the solution on using Gson to deserialise an serialise XMLGregorianCalendar datatype by this code

```
public class XMLGregorianCalendarConverter {
public static class Serializer implements JsonSerializer{
    public Serializer(){
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Object t, Type type, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        XMLGregorianCalendar xgcal = (XMLGregorianCalendar) t;
        return new JsonPrimitive(xgcal.toXMLFormat());
    }
}

public static class Deserializer implements JsonDeserializer{

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonElement t, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext context) {
        try 
        {
            return DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(t.getAsString());
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

this code worked fine in java desktop environment. but in android i got some Logcat saying "xerces.jaxp.datatype.DataTypeFactoryImpl not found".
I tryed to include xerces from apache as mentioned in one workaround for this kind of problem in this forum. but i got some dalvik error and i was unable to build my project.

please i need help on  how to fix this. I dont want to change anything on the Rest side.

Answer (score 0):

If you use proguard, then you can try to add this to the proguard.txt file:

```
-dontwarn org.apache.xml.resolver.**
-dontwarn org.xml.sax.**
```